# Are there any differences between Mario and Luigi?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

After beating the castle of Special World 1  you unlock Luigi as a playable character. I played as him for a bit but I didn't notice any game play differences between Mario and Luigi. I remember in Super Mario Galaxy that Luigi could jump further, but he took longer to stop.

Are there any differences between Mario and Luigi, or are they identical?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

He skids a bit more (faster/more momentum?) and jumps higher (Luigi can triple jump), but the biggest difference that I've noticed though is that he wears **green** and that he is Mario's **brother**.

"Tanooki Luigi" wears a Kitsune suit.

Answer (score 11):

[Apparently](http://www.mariowiki.com/Luigi#Super_Mario_3D_Land) it's the [same as in Galaxy](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/620831-super-mario-3d-land/61180840) - he jumps a bit higher/further, but he has poorer traction.

A minor graphical difference, but his [Tanooki Suit](http://www.mariowiki.com/Tanooki_Mario) supposedly also looks a bit more like a Kitsune.

Comment: Traditionally (going back to _SMB2US_) Luigi has a better jump distance and hang time than Mario.

Answer (score 7):

He jumps a bit higher and skids a bit farther. he can also run faster. He can also triple-jump.